# How to convert relative object coordinates to absolute

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a button on form, which opens popup menu. I need to open this popup menu right under button. `ShowPopup` function accepts absolute desktop coordinates. How to calculate absolute coordinates, if I know button position on form?

Currently I'm using this trick:

```
Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
Private Declare Function GetFocus Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim r As RECT
    Dim chwnd As Long
    Dim h As Long

    Me.Text1.SetFocus
    chwnd = GetFocus
    Me.Command1.SetFocus
    h = GetWindowRect(chwnd, r)
    CommandBars("PopupMenu").ShowPopup r.Left, r.Bottom
End Sub
```

It works, but additional TextBox `Text1` right under the button, which allows to get absolute position using API is not really good solution, wanted to calculate instead of using artificial "bookmarks"